# Imposing Constraints reduce degree of freedom

Tags: regression, machine-learning, splines, degrees-of-freedom, constraint

This question is from [Statistical learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) Page 271 Section 7.4.2 Where it was stated (not explained) that 
Imposing three constraints to a 8 degree of freedom of the model reduce its degree of freedom from 8 to 5.

How imposing three constraints i.e. continuity , continuity of the First derivative and continuity of the Second derivative reduces the degree of Freedom of a model

Can anyone explain why imposing these constraints on a model reduce the degree of freedom of a model?